# Azure: Where should a management certificate reside for use by a Cloud Service

Tags: azure, x509certificate, azure-management

I have a worker role that is used to provision databases. In order to do this it has to hit the Azure Management API and to do this it requires a certificate.

You can store certificates in the portal against the subscription (Settings tab) or against individual cloud services. Where should the certificate be stored?

Answer (score 0):

Worker role that needs to talk to Management API needs to have the .PFX certificate uploaded into it as if it is an SSL cert (against individual service).

Matching public cert (.cer) needs to be uploaded to the Management Certificates area, against the subscription itself.

HTH

Comment: For step-by-step instructions, you may find this blog post useful: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/07/25/consuming-windows-azureservice-management-api-from-webworker-rolethe-easy-way/